# probability of the event $B \cap C \cap A$

Tags: probability

Events $A$, $B$ and $C$ occur with respective probabilities $0.52$, $0.13$ and $0.07$. Event $A$ is independent of the events $B$ and $C$. Event $A$ is also independent of the joint occurrence of $B$ and $C$. If the probability of the event $B \cap C$ is $0.03$, compute the probability of the event $B \cap C \cap A$.

I tried to solve it: 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(B \cap C \cap A) & = \Pr(B \cap C)\Pr(A)\\
                     & = 0.03 \cdot 0.52\\
                     & = 0.0156
\end{align*}

Is it correct? If not, then please tell me the correct answer or at least tell me the final answer to check by myself.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.

$A$ and $B \cap C$ are independent, so $P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(A)  P(B \cap C) = 0.03 \times 0.52 = 0.0156$.